# What to call a civ/nation that has technology but does not utilize or rely upon it?

Tags: technological-development, civilization, post-apocalypse, names

What would you call a civilization or is their some sort of adjective where people live their lives perhaps mostly in villages and communities, farming etc. but also have available technologies such as computers or simple machinery (probably fossil fueled).

I don't mean our modern world where many 3rd world countries may be a farming community but have access to smart phones/computers, more that it naturally developed this way; they have discovered modern technology but have not revolutionized.

I have added the tag of post apocalyptic because it could perhaps be a reason for the world ending up this way but probably not. (Because if you think Fallout etc. they have access to technology but live in tiny communities).

Comment: What do you want the word for?  My first instinct is that when a group has access to technology and chooses not to use it, the reason why they choose to use it is far more important than the mere fact that they don't use it.  "Backward" and "idealistic" and "reserved" are all words I can think of to describe such people, but giving them different reasons for choosing to do so.

Comment: I would like to say cultural (sorry I know that is broad too), they like to live their villagey life but happen to harness machinery to help their lives.

I don't think they would have much or any contact with others, or the world is perhaps small so there are only a few villages.

So travel is not much of a necessity.

Comment: Thinking of real world examples: [*golden rice*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_rice). What do you call people who would rather let nations starve rather than use technology? It doesn't seem to have a specific name.

Comment: Wise. | Amish. | cf Larry Niven's "The Integral Trees" / "Smokering" and related tales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionalist: The nearest that I can come up with is religious doctrine like the [Ordnung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordnung) as applied by the Amish. A more pressing version would be a [taboo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taboo) against using technology.

Another reason to refrain from all the trappings of civilization and city life would be [survivalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivalism).

References:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordnung
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taboo
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivalism

Comment: Thanks, I might go with something like "a technological but traditional civilization".

Answer (score 1):

I can imagine interstellar colonists being like this, their ship can fabricate advanced technology but they don't have any large scale infrastructure, so no concrete, no rebar, no bitumen roads. Having come from overcrowded cities the colonists will be glad to leave the ship, they'll build houses out of local materials, grow fresh food and settle down to raise families.

The ship itself will become a jealously guarded engineer nest.

Comment: That's similar to Larry Niven's "The Integral Trees" / "Smokering" and related tales.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the association with utopia such a society could be described as Arcadian.

While artistic portrayals of Arcadia vary they generally show a low level of visible technology and share an implicit assumption of the superiority of the rural over the urban.